# http post not working on wp7, name field is not sent over

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-7

ok so I look around at tons of post here and else where. what I have is a php script like this.

```
<?php


//gets the post from the phone app
$calendar = $_POST[ 'calendar' ];

//converts the post into a string for manipulation
$xml = simplexml_load_string($calendar); 

rest of code omitted
```

then in C# I have this

```
string Event_xml;
Event_xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><calendar><event><event_id></event_id><title>"+ local_title +"</title><venue_id>1</venue_id><contact_id>1</contact_id><description>"+ local_description +"</description><category_id>1</category_id><user_id>" + local_ID + "</user_id><group_id>1</group_id><status_id>1</status_id><date>" + local_startDate + "</date><starttime>" + local_startTime + "</starttime><endDate>" + local_endDate + "</endDate><endtime>" + local_endTime + "</endtime></event></calendar>";

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var URI = new Uri("http://jasonsftp.no-ip.info/test/EventInput.php");
        wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);

        wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", Event_xml);
```

when I get the response back it is error

Notice: Undefined index: calendar in htdocs\test\testinput.php on line 11
Array
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in htdocs\test\testinput.php on line 30

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in htdocs\test\testinput.php on line 30

now if I use a standard html post like this:

```
<form action="http://jasonsftp.no-ip.info/test/testinput.php?" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="calendar" value="mydata" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

it works just fine.
so the name="calendar" is what in C# I cant get to go over with my current code.

any help would be appreciated. I hope this is not very complicated. I think I am just missing something but I did not find anything when reading through the class descriptions.

thanks
Jason

Answer (score 0):

So I found what works here is what I had to do in the c#

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();


        string sendData = "";
        var URI = new Uri("http://jasonsftp.no-ip.info/test/testinput.php");
        wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


        sendData += "&title="+local_title;
        sendData += "&event_id=";
        sendData += "&venue_id=1";
        sendData += "&contact_id=1";
        sendData += "&description=" + local_description;
        sendData += "&category_id=1";
        sendData += "&user_id=" + local_ID;
        sendData += "&group_id=1";
        sendData += "&status_id=1";
        sendData += "&date=" + local_startDate;
        sendData += "&start_time=" + local_startTime;
        sendData += "&end_date=" + local_endDate;
        sendData += "&end_time=" + local_endTime;

        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = sendData.Length.ToString();
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);

        wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", sendData);
```

and for the php here is what I did to make it work

```
<?php

$title = $_POST['title'];
$event_id = $_POST['event_id'];
$venue_id = $_POST['venue_id'];
$contact_id = $_POST['contact_id'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$group_id = $_POST['group_id'];
$status_id = $_POST['status_id'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$start_time = $_POST['start_time'];
$end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
$end_time = $_POST['end_time'];
$latitude = "";
$longitude = "";
```

with that I am able to get the values from the phone and add them to the database as needed.